# Java JRE Updating issue with CentOS

Tags: java, linux, centos

I have just recently installed CentOS on my little server box. I am in the process of transferring my servers from Windows Server to Linux/CentOS, and I'm running into a small problem.

I checked "Install java" when I was installing CentOS because I thought it would speed up the process. However, it installed Java 7, and I need to use Java 8 because our code uses a bunch of new features in Java 8.

I have tried removing Java JRE 7 manually, downloading an rpm, and using `yum`. However, it seems that Java 7 is still installed, or is overriding the Java JRE 8 install.

I can provide any logs neccessary. Thank you!

---

rpm -qa 'java*'

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64
javapackages-tools-3.4.1-6.el7_0.noarch
```

Comment: What version of CentOS? What does "updating manually" mean? What RPMs did you download? What did you try with `yum`? What java packages are installed (i.e. What does `rpm -qa 'java*'` say?)?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry for the vague question. By "updating manually" I meant "removing the java folders manually". With "yum", I tried `yum localinstall jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm` with the downloaded RPM and I also tried double-clicking the icon.

Comment: If you manually removed directories installed via yum packages you may have greatly confused/harmed your system. Just for the record.

Comment: @EtanReisner I put them back right afterwards because it didn't work, no worries. Anyway, thanks for your and LarsGendner's help, I've got it working now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I did on my CentOS7 box:

```
yum list installed java*
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless
```

Then I downloaded the JDK RPM from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html (I chose jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm). Then installed it using

```
sudo yum localinstall jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm
```

For me that worked. To track down your `java` binary, you can do it like this:

```
[~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
[~]$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22  3. Sep 02:49 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
[~]$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34  3. Sep 02:49 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin/java
```

If your Java binary is linked in /etc/alternatives, you can use [alternatives(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) to choose the desired version.

Comment: This worked like a charm, ignore my previous comment. Thanks so much!

Comment: CentOS 7 almost certainly has official `java-1.8.0-openjdk` packages too for the record.

Comment: I read about some urban legend that Eclipse is not compatible with OpenJDK, so I went for the superstitious approach and chose Oracle's JDK. But this has got nothing to do with this question, I admit.

Comment: @LarsGendner It's a server computer, so I'm not going to be needing to run Eclipse. Good to know though. Thanks!